# Python parsing XML to CSV Encoding issues

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have a large number of XML files in a folder that I am parsing into a CSV file. My code looks like this:

```py
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import csv
    import os




    fields = [
        ('ID', 'FHRSID'),
        ('businessname', 'BusinessName'),
        ('businesstype', 'BusinessType'),
        ('address1', 'AddressLine1'),
        ('address2', 'AddressLine2'),
        ('address3', 'AddressLine3'),
        ('address4', 'AddressLine4'),
        ('postcode', 'PostCode'),
        ('longitude', 'Geocode/Longitude'),
        ('latitude', 'Geocode/Latitude')]

    path = '/***/****/****/XML'
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        tree = ET.parse(fullname)


    with open(r'outputdata.csv', 'wb') as f_businesslist:
        csv_businessdata = csv.DictWriter(f_businesslist, fieldnames=[field for field, match in fields])
        csv_businessdata.writeheader()

        for node in tree.iter('EstablishmentDetail'):
            row = {}

            for field_name, match in fields:
                try:
                    row[field_name] = node.find(match).text
                except AttributeError as e:
                    row[field_name] = ''



            csv_businessdata.writerow(row)
```

It does what it is supposed to do but then i get an encoding error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./XMLtoCsv.py", line 42, in <module>
    csv_businessdata.writerow(row)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone help? I have spent a lot of time reading through some similar problems but nothing seems to help. I am very new to this so I assume it is something stupid I have done or failed to do. Many thanks

Comment: For python 2.7 see codecs.open().

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode Unicode explicitly when you are opening the file.

```
with open(r'outputdata.csv', 'wb', encoding='utf-8) as f_businesslist:
```

It seems you are using python 2.7. I would also suggest switching to python 3.x.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried that and it didn't work. I get the following error:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./XMLtoCsv.py", line 27, in <module>
    with open(r'outputdata.csv', 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f_businesslist:
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: same error : TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: After some  search, it seems python 2 doesn't support encoding as an argument. try something like `f_businesslist.decode("UTF-8")` in your DictWriter